# How to give gridview header row 3-D look?

Tags: css, gridview

I need to apply 3D style to my gridview's header row. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by 3D? you can apply some CSS3 styles to get started.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.textfixer.com/resources/css-tables.php

Here you find how to style a css to 3d. Just apply it as Headerstyle in your GridView?

Comment: Other than that i think you have to download or make use of something like the Telerik GridView extender.